# Initializing EJB context in main function?

Tags: java, initialization, ejb, program-entry-point

After forced switching from Spring to EJB (EJB3) in my workspace, I find it problematic to rewrite the utility functions, that made some manual tasks like creating a few records or importing some dictionaries into database.

In Spring I could easily initialize the application by calling `new ClassPathAXmlApplicationContext('spring.xml')`. Is there any similar utility class for EJB? I'm using EJB implementation from **Websphere 8**, to be more specific.

Asking google for "Initializing EJB context" gave me nothing useful, maybe it was not correct search phrase?

Answer (score 0):

In case you're starting (embeded) EJB container or doing something of this kind, singleton session bean can be annotated with @Startup annotation and it's @PostConstruct life cycle method will be invoked after container startup.

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class StartupBean {
  @PostConstruct
  void init {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

**EDIT**:
There's WebSpehere [documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/tejb_dvemcontainer.html?cp=SSAW57_8.0.0%2F1-3-0-10-1-3&lang=en) on how to run embeded container and invoke EJB's. But note that embeded container has to support only EJB Lite specification:

> The embeddable container does not support the use of Contexts and
>   Dependency Injection (CDI).

Comment: But I'm asking, how to start that embedded EJB container.